# How to simulate Google Plus vote up animation on Android

Tags: android, animation, google-plus

Do you have any idea/reference about how to create vote up animation of Google Plus?
I think it has two animations, one for button (view) and second one applies to view group.
Any suggestion would be appreciated. Thanks.

[image] [image]

[image] [image]

Comment: Looks just like animation set, translate and scale... with listener to change color and set text and the end of the first animation.

Comment: I tried with translate and I could get something close to however is not as smooth as G+ :(

Comment: It seems translate+scale with cycle interpolator, then when it finishes, a shake animation starts on the whole viewgroup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay good news is after spending some hours finally solution found. 
This is my code hope it helps other people in future.

1- under res/anim create first xml file (in my case btn_anim.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<set
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator">

    <translate
        android:fromXDelta="0.0"
        android:fromYDelta="0.0"
        android:toXDelta="0.0"
        android:toYDelta="-75.0"
        android:duration="350"
        android:fillBefore="true"
        android:fillAfter="true" />

    <scale
        android:fromXScale="1.0"
        android:fromYScale="1.0"
        android:toXScale="1.05"
        android:toYScale="1.0"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:duration="350"
        android:fillBefore="true"
        android:fillAfter="true"/>
</set>
```

2- under res/anim create second xml file (in my case layout_anim.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<set
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator">

    <scale
        android:fromXScale="1.0"
        android:fromYScale="1.0"
        android:toXScale="0.95"
        android:toYScale="0.95"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:duration="100"
        android:fillBefore="true"
        android:fillAfter="true"/>

</set>
```

3- In your Activity (or Fragment) add these code:

```
...
private ScrollView scrollView; // This is my container. Yours may be different
private Animation btnAnim;
private Animation layoutAnim;
...

@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        // Getting context
        context = getActivity().getApplicationContext();

        btnAnim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.btn_anim);
        btnAnim.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                layoutAnim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.layout_anim);
                scrollView.startAnimation(layoutAnim);
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

            }
        });

        // create view
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_browse_single, container, false);

        scrollView = (ScrollView) view.findViewById(R.id.scrollView);

        myButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.myButton);
        myButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                btnFancy.startAnimation(btnAnim);
            }
        });

        Log.i(TAG, "View created");
        return view;
    }
```